# how to create store procedure in cakephp models

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi I want to create mysql stored procedure using models in cakephp. Because i dont have to access database directly.
my stored procedure is,

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE testfun()
   BEGIN
     SELECT id ,name FROM table_name;
   END;
```

so that i am creating using

```
   $this->Model->query("Delimiter $$ CREATE PROCEDURE testfun()
   BEGIN
     SELECT id ,name FROM table_name;
   END$$");
```

but it shows the error.. how can i create procedure using models

Comment: If CakePHP can interact with the database, so can you.

Comment: ya i have to get values from db, but i dont have permission phpmyadmin login.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is not the only way to access a database. However, for whatever project you're working on, tell your boss you need the tools to do the job. There's no reason to try to hack it.

Comment: i wanna create procedure in model itself as dynamically.

Comment: `but it shows the error` - what error?

Comment: Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE testfun (' at line 1

Comment: I don't think creating a procedure in the model is consider to be dynamic. You can mock the procedure as cake-functions and that would be more dynamic.